# error accessing transactional temp table in Oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, transactional

I am running into an issue running some UTPL/SQL unit tests in 12c. The environment we have set up runs the tests against an 11g and 12c server and the same unit tests that are passing in 11g are failing in 12c.

The code I am able to provide is limited due to obvious security concerns, but I think just the general description of the problem will be enough. The problems appears to be with the calling functions which are autonomous transactions. This call is basically just adding data to several tables and creating a new product.So it's set up to commit if successful and rollback all product creation when a failure occurs. it does call nested functions that are also autonomous transactions. The problem is when running this in 12c we get:

```
ORA-14450: attempt to access a transactional temp table already in use
```

Not sure why this is suddenly a problem in 12c. Has anyone else run unto this? Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using autonomous transactions, never mind nested ones? It sounds like you're throwing transaction control out of the window...

Comment: Are you trying to do DDL on a global temporary table inside code?